# Save thrift data in database

Tags: thrift

I need to store received thrift data in database, so I can read it later and send it by thrift client again. How to store it i.e as blob without doing some temp serialization object from thrift generated class.

`thrift client A`->`thrift server A`->`database`->`thrift client B`->`thrift server B`

Solution:

```
class LocalRpcHandler : virtual public LocalRpcIf {
public:

    shared_ptr<TMemoryBuffer> memBuff;
    shared_ptr<TBinaryProtocol> binProt;
....

    void send(const Sample& sample) {

        sample.write(binProt.get());
                saveToDatabase(memBuff);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ implementation has a [TProtocolTap](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/cpp/src/thrift/protocol/TProtocolTap.h), which can be used to do that. It's easy to write something similar for other languages, just have a look at the C++ code.

It basically allows to connect two protocols into one. The second protocol could then do whatever you want with the data.

Comment: I have updated question to be more clear. I am not sure if TProtocolTap can help me. I still need to write custom protocol?

Comment: Ok, understand. The requirements "storing as BLOB" and "without temp serialization" are excluding each other. If we ignore that ;-), I'd recommend to serialize it into a memory stream. It should not be that hard to put that into your database. The details on how to do this vary depending on your Server A language and the DBMS you plan to use, so it's hard to go into detail here without knowing more.

Comment: server A(c++), database(sqlite). So you mean to serialize before sending to server A (send serialized data in i.e string field)?

Comment: Either that way, then you basically get cliA->srvA->serializer->cliB->srvB, or use the protocol tap to split the incoming request at srvA into serializer and cliB. Key question is, if you want to forward the call immediately or if there may be some (possibly longer) delay between srvA and cliB.

Comment: Serialization: SQLite supports BLOBs, so the request could be stored as byte array. The TMemoryBuffer Transport can be used to prepare the data for your BLOB.

Comment: Of course there are possible longer delays. Database is like buffer for me, if server B is offline.

Comment: Ok. Done. On server A side, in rpc function I serialize parameters with use of TMemoryBuffer.

Comment: By the way, what you do sounds a lot like a classical message queueing scenario. Did you consider using ZeroMQ or sth. similar? See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-812

Comment: You are right. But I don't known ZeroMQ. You mean to throwing away thrift and use ZeroMQ as transport and i.e protobuf as message format? So new architecture will be client A -> ZeroMQ -> server B

Comment: I just want to mention, that there might be other architectural options that could be worth to be taken into consideration. I don't say you should throw away Thrift. Have you read the JIRA ticket? I know too little about your particular use case and the overall context to tell you what's the best thing to do in your situation.